# Clearing Cell J if Cell B is greater than Cell G

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to implement a basic stock control system.

The project can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bvp8q8yflwh4fq3/stockSystem.xlsm?dl=0), and a picture [here](http://prntscr.com/fa2vr9).

Basically, when the stock is lower than the reorder level (B <= G), the Order Stock? column (I) should show yes. When a member of staff orders stock, they mark the Ordered? (J) column as Yes. This should then cause the Order Stock? (I) column to be blank. This works so far.

The issue is that when we get more stock, this is entered on the Received sheet, changing the Quantity in Stock (B) value. What I would like is that if B > G, clear J. This doesn't seem to be working, but I can't figure out why.

The VBA code I'm using is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Cells(Target.Row, 2) > Cells(Target.Row, 7) Then
    Cells(Target.Row, 10).Value = ""
Else
    Cells(Target.Row, 9).Value = "Yes"
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon!

What happens is that by entering data in Received sheet is not triggering Worksheet_Change of Stock sheet. When you change the data in Received sheet as you have a formula in Column B of Stock sheet the event triggered is Worksheet_Calculate.

I've uploaded a changed for you [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ism0ukyh7m7m0zh/stockSystem.xlsm?dl=0) where I made the Worksheet_Change of Received sheet update data for you.

Please fell free to ask additional questions.

Best Regards!

Comment: I would like to see your code without being forced to go to a third-party website. You should post your code here. Besides, what about this post in, say, 1 year?

Comment: Posts should answer the question in their own,  not referring to links. Please include your code in your answer.

Comment: This works great. If you could add the code into your answer with an explanation I'll accept it. Thanks!